# How many points have topics closed for being off-topic received?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, closed-questions, off-topic

Stack Overflow frequently is on the first page of Google search results and I am surprised how often the valuable question has been closed for being off-topic despite numerous up votes and answers with up votes. How many points have topics closed for being off-topic received? Is there data to suggest that questions with points and quality answers should be re-opened? Should those who vote to close a topic that receives traction be "punished" when there are more people who find the question and answers valuable up vote more than votes to close?

Comment: From the [first page alone alone](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=closed%3ayes), I count 18535 up-votes. But, honestly, upvotes are not a good indication of on/off-topicness. Remember [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461961/i-need-help-asking-a-girl-out) (10kers only)? If you feel strongly about a certain question, simply vote to re-open, if the community feels the same way, the question will be re-opened!

Comment: @DaveChen That question made me want to slap some people!

Comment: @Dave lol that question is hilarious

Comment: Why are these comments instead of answers?

Comment: I'd also like to point out that upvoting is a +15 privilege while close-voting is +3000, and deleting +10,000. If anything, the users upvoting on a poor question should be punished! (But hey, I've voted on my share of poor questions, and voting should be anonymous -- and not carry any consequences, unless you're serially voting, in which case the system will handle that automatically.) The current system (closing, and voting) are (in my opinion) fine the way they are.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200122/why-are-the-best-questions-the-ones-which-have-been-closed

Comment: Related: “Experts may have the best answers, but beginners have the best questions.” https://the-pastry-box-project.net/d-keith-robinson/2014-may-7

Answer (score 10):

Upvotes aren't really indicative of an on-topic question. They are indicative of a question that people may find useful, funny, or cool, but that's pretty much about it.*

> Should those who vote to close a topic that receives traction be "punished" when there are more people who find the question and answers valuable up vote more than votes to close?

Think about what kind of a signal this would send. You would create a punishment for those users who care most about the site (and have earned the privilege to vote to close, something they get no reward for) on the basis of votes (which practically anyone can cast). It's difficult to think of a more effective way to *discourage* community moderation altogether.

<sub>* A huge fight was had on Meta over the past two years concerning what should happen to off-topic questions. There were two main camps: the deletionists (who argued that any off-topic content needs to be removed completely), and the those who argued that while off-topic questions need to be closed, they shouldn't be deleted altogether, but perhaps archived. Unfortunately, the deletionists won, so the current policy is not only closing but also deleting all off-topic content.</sub>

Comment: Certainly there are examples of questions being grossly off-topic, but the volume of closed questions that rank highly on Google seems to suggest that far more questions are closed than necessary. Useful questions with useful being shut down suggests a product design problem, not a problem with the question.

Comment: @jeremiahLee can you show some examples?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/112396/how-do-i-remove-the-passphrase-for-the-ssh-key-without-having-to-create-a-new-ke/112409

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473185/regex-javascript-image-file-extension/10473222

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12389611/grep-a-list-of-specific-files

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12437790/when-to-use-couchdb-over-mongodb-and-vice-versa

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409338/examples-of-the-best-soap-rest-rpc-web-apis-and-why-do-you-like-them-and-what

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/412141/best-engineered-rest-apis

Comment: Those are horrible types of questions  whose merits have been discussed at nauseam here on Meta, with the result that the community doesn't want them, for very specific reasons. Not all questions that are popular or useful have a place on Stack Overflow; that's not a "design problem"

Comment: I didn't find them to be "horrible questions"—I found them to be quite useful to me. The number of upvotes, stars, and views suggests many other people found the questions to be useful too.

Comment: I have, too, but they come with problems in the long run. Some discussion: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102969/why-are-people-closing-what-x-is-best-questions http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192461/question-of-type-what-is-the-best-why-not-where-to-go there is a *lot* more

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/ http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62014/can-you-please-disable-the-subjective-and-argumentative-closing-reason-feature http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88328/what-is-the-moderator-rationale-behind-closing-and-locking-6kview-cws-that-have/ http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180335/are-there-good-list-questions-as-opposed-to-bad-list-questions/

Comment: Another very useful, top ranked result on Google that has been punished by this policy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/294167/what-are-the-most-useful-intellij-idea-keyboard-shortcuts

Comment: @JeremiahLee, that is **not** a useful question for SE. It would make a great blog post, or perhaps forum thread, but it isn't a good fit for the SE format. SE was designed to get clear answers to solvable problems -- 'the best' shortcuts are neither answerable nor problems.

Comment: Perhaps my problem was needing a better way to do a repetitive task for which a keyboard shortcut would be a solution. A strict interpretation of what is considered a problem limits the usefulness of Stack Exchange.

Comment: Another #1 Google search result with meaningful answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393961/how-to-import-existing-sql-files-in-postgresql-8-4

Comment: @Jeremiah I'm not sure I share your definition of "meaningful." What does the answer add that the documentation directly underneath doesn't?

Comment: The ability to find an answer is as important as an answer existing. The documentation in this case outlines the available options of a command, but does not provide an example for the specific use case.

Answer (score 5):

## Getting the Data

You can do this using the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries) though you may have to limit your query to a few months due to the volume of data and the limitations before something times out. Using [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/142949/176971/score-on-closed-questions) counting closed questions with score over 0, I got a total of 480,607 score on closed questions, which means there were at least 2.4 million reputation gained on close votes (score is the sum of up- and downvotes, and it takes 2.5 downvotes to equal an upvote reputation wise, so the 2.4 million is the minimum in this case and is likely higher).

## Why the Data is Useless

On-topic and upvoted are not correlated. An amusing off-topic post in a popular tag will likely get far more upvotes than a very good on-topic question in an unpopular tag. Judging usefulness or topicality based solely on score is probably not the right decision.

Just a couple months ago [there was a whole lot of hubbub on buying croissants](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190106/dealing-with-find-out-whos-going-to-buy-the-croissants). The question has since been deleted, but needless to say it was quite popular. It was also off-topic.

Batch re-opening highly scored closed questions is (re-)opening pandora's box.

## What You Can Do to Rectify the Situation

If you find glaring examples of a great highly-scored question that is on-topic for the site, you can cast a reopen vote and stick it in the queue where the community can decide. If you don't have the reputation to cast re-open votes, you can make a meta post asking why it is closed, and the community can vote to re-open it if they agree with your assessment.

Comment: It takes a lot of time to earn the reputation to cast reopen votes; time that many people simply don't have. And users with low repudiation don't tend to get prompt, useful answers. I'm with Jeremiah on this one, myself.

Comment: @Owen, Yes, it does take time -- time to understand the community concepts of moderating the quality of the site. If you aren't willing to invest in learning the standards, why should you be trusted to decide what falls within those standards?

Comment: No, more time than that. I had a good idea of the concepts and standards of this site a very long time before I had any real quantity of reputation here. The concept (in a wider sense) reminds me of Ashe Dryden's excellent blogpost [The ethics of unpaid labor and the OSS community](http://ashedryden.com/blog/the-ethics-of-unpaid-labor-and-the-oss-community) — not every site-user has the [privilege](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privilege_%28social_inequality%29) to be able to invest the time to gain that much rept. The users with the rept are _not_ representative of the whole userbase.

Comment: @Owen, I never said they are representations of the whole user base. Just because *you* are able to understand site guidelines doesn't mean that all users under 3k rep do. It's like a drinking age, or an age to be able to drive, or a voting age -- just because some people under that age are able doesn't mean that it is practical (or preferable) to do away with the limitation. I've been here a year and don't have the privilege on SO, but if it does mean that much to you, then participate in the community and get the rep.

Comment: I think you're missing my point. Not everyone has the privilege to invest the time to get reputation. I am arguing that the limitation is the fault here, not users' inability to devote time (for whatever reason) sufficient to acquire the reputation necessary. I think this is a general problem with many sites where editors are outnumbered by readers (Wikipedia has a bunch of related, but different problems, for similar reasons). But I think the core problem is that the community who are able to vote on things like this are not representative of the community of site-users.

Comment: @Owen, all rep does is gives you special tools (privileges), but those without the tools (like myself) can post here and get things done on the merit of their idea regardless of time invested in gathering rep. There are a lot of well-received posts from new users here (as well as low-rep users) regardless of their time spent investing in the site. If you have a specific issue about this, I suggest asking a separate question, but suggesting that rep requirements should be removed without an alternative suggestion would be anarchy.